# How to change the image of a ImageView from DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-dialogfragment

So basically i have a Fragment class where i have a ImageView, where i have not set any image yet. So i want to do this from a Dialog Box where i have list and on the click of any of the items to add the image in the Fragment where the ImageView is situated. The image is a rectangle made in a xml file. If i add it from it's class the Fragment class it works. But i need it to add it from the Dialog Box.

And i tried this all day and nothing works, all that i get is nullPointerException in the same place where i try to call the add of the image in all the way i tried.

here is the code that i have got to after i tried a lot :).

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BrickMessageBoxGreen extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_green);
        builder.setItems(R.array.greenBricks_array,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
                        Arkitektur ark = new Arkitektur();
                        ImageView img = (ImageView)ark.getView().findViewById(R.id.green_brick);
                        ark.addGreenBrick(img);
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And here is the class where i have the ImageView:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Arkitektur extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {

    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;
    ViewGroup _root;
    private View arkitektur;

    ImageView greenBrick;
    ImageView redBrick;
    ImageView yellowBrick;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        arkitektur = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arkitektur, container, false);
        //arkitektur.findViewById(R.id.green_brick).setOnTouchListener(this);
        //greenBrick = (ImageView) arkitektur.findViewById(R.id.green_brick);
        //arkitektur.findViewById(R.id.root).setOnDragListener(this);
        //arkitektur.findViewById(R.id.bottom_container).setOnDragListener(this);

        //addGreenBrick();

        _root = (ViewGroup) arkitektur.findViewById(R.id.root);
        _root.setOnDragListener(this);

        return arkitektur;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX()*2;
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY()*2;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
//              layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
//              layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        _root.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
            View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout to = (LinearLayout) v;
            to.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void addGreenBrick(View v)
    {
        v.findViewById(R.id.green_brick).setOnTouchListener(this);
        greenBrick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.green_brick);
        greenBrick.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_brick);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with  Tamilselvan Kalimuthu, just let your fragment implement a listener and set it as an attribute of BrickMessageBoxGreen class.

**Edit:**

Added some code to clarify the idea.

BrickMessageBoxGreen class:

```
public OnClickDialogListener listener //Attribute of your class

public void setDialogListener(OnClickDialogListener  l){ //Setting the listener
    this.listener = l;
}


new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //Changing onClick method
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
            this.listener.onDialogClicked("green");
                    }
                });
```

Arkitektur class:

```
public interface OnClickDialogListener { //Your listener definition, you could place it elsewhere
    void onDialogClicked(String colorName);
}

public class Arkitektur extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener, OnClickDialogListener  { //Implementing your listener interface

public void onDialogClicked(String colorName){//Method implementation
if(colorName.equals("green")){
    addGreenBrick();
}else if(colorName.equals("red")){
    addRedBrick();
}else if(colorName.equals("yellor")){
    addYellowBrick();
}
}
```

Comment: I implemented the interface and everything but still get the null exception for the line :       ImageView img = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.green_brick);

Comment: Hi Tacx, I edited my code, now you just passing the color wich should be changed to your fragment, please take a look

Comment: This is incredible still gives me null exception :D ... for the same line:       this.listener.onDialogClicked("green");

Comment: Are yout setting the listener? It seems that this.listener == null, please always debug your code and test it. In order to improve my answer, I need to know why are you creating such application, do you already have OOP background?

Comment: It's an app for my school(Android Development - so i' new to Android SDK i worked more with C# until now) and i got stuck here with this. I need to have multiple TABS and on each tab to be able to add bricks(drawings) with a Text from a Array and you choice that word from the dialog box where i added the list of words. And i want to be able to add the drawing(brick) on the fragment(Tab) that the user is currently on.

Comment: Sorry, I can not help you, you are supposed build such application alone. But if you are going to be a software engineer, here are some interesting links: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/,  http://blog.codinghorror.com/please-dont-learn-to-code/, http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-you-want-to-be-a-programmer/

Comment: Actually we can use any resource and i'm not asking you to build it for me i just gut stuck here and i don't know how to get pass it :). Thanks anyways for the help so far ;) !